# How to use of FLTK in-box.get_string()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fltk

The following code is a small part of an app. For that app I need to use of *in_box.get_string()*. The declaration and definition of in_box are in [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/) address in *GUI.h* and *GUI.cpp* files.

For integers, it works fine. That is, if I use *in_box.get_int()* it gets the number entered to the *in_box* and returns that number as an `integer`. But the problem is that, it doesn't work for `strings`, as is expected. And when using strings, I get errors!

For example in code below I have used a `string` *s*.

```
#include <GUI.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Graph_lib;

class Calculator : public Window {
public:
    Calculator(Point, int, int, const string&);

private:
    //Widgets
    Button show_button;
    In_box enter_box;

    void show() { getstr(); cout <<s; }

    void getstr() {
        s = enter_box.get_string();
    }

  static void cb_show(Address, Address pw) { reference_to<Calculator>(pw).show(); }
  string s;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

Calculator::Calculator(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title):
    Window(xy, w, h, title),
    show_button(Point(x_max()-110, 440), 90, 35, "Show", cb_show),
    enter_box(Point(x_max()-400, 158), 245, 40,  "Enter"){

    attach(enter_box);
    attach(show_button);
}

int main()
{
    Calculator cal(Point(100,100), 600, 500, "Calculator");
    return gui_main();
}
```

There are 8 *warnings* and two *errors*. Errors are these:

> *Error    9  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall Graph_lib::In_box::get_string(void)"
>   (?get_string@In_box@Graph_lib@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
>   Calculator::getstr(void)"
>   (?getstr@Calculator@@AAEXXZ)  C:\Users\ME\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\test_3\test_3\test_3.obj Error  10  error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals  C:\Users\ME\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\test_3\Debug\test_3.exe*

The errors say, that is a linker problem but my *linker input*'s file list is as follows and it has worked (almost) fine so far.

*fltkd.lib

wsock32.lib

comctl32.lib

fltkjpegd.lib

fltkimagesd.lib*

My compiler is MS VS 2012. And machine is Win 7.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiled FLTK in Debug and Release mode, make sure you have the linker dependencies right: the files you list for Debug, and **fltk.lib**, **wsock32.lib**, **comctl32.lib**, **fltkjpegd.lib** and **fltkimages.lib** for Release (notice absence of "d" at the end of the names).

Secondly, even though I don't think it causes the linker error (but leads to other weird problems), make sure you've included all the Stroustrup graphic library files in your Visual Studio project: **fltk.h**, **Graph.h**, **GUI.h**, **Point.h**, **Simple_window.h**, **std_lib_facilities.h**, **Window.h**, **Graph.cpp**, **GUI.cpp** and **Window.cpp**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The list of the files I copied into the linker dependencies are as I said in the question. I don't know how to change the   _fltkimagesd.lib_ to _fltkimages.lib_ and doesn't this cause else problems! I included all mentioned library files but no changes.

Comment: I've done a little write-up [here](http://stringgettitle.blogspot.ca/2014/12/installing-fltk-133-under-visual-studio.html).

Comment: Well. The source you provided is very valuable. Some time ago, when I couldn't be able to setup and run FLTK successfully on VS 2012, that source could be like a treasure! Anyway, I installed it at the time, but not exactly the same way as yours. Big difference is that I didn't install in both release and debug mode, just one of them. Anyway, since FLTK in PPP is used only for chapters 12-16 (and I'm at chapter 17 now) and also since Stroustrup doesn't recommend FLTK for real work on graphics (he recommend Qt), so I'm not very concern about FLTK. I thank you for all of your helps.

Comment: I have another question :), I have written a small app using that FLTK. It's a calculator and it's my best app ever. Now how can I publish it on the web? Or how to enclose it within a team?    Can you help me in that case? Thanks again.

Comment: Check out [this here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9(v=vs.110).aspx), I guess.